# How best to have 'mini-tables' with the same data (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

**Overview**

I am looking for best practice in design, more than I'm looking for an exact answer. In other words, the answer doesn't have to brute force what I'm trying to do if there is a better way to do it.

**Problem**

I have some data with an ID and a Timestamp streaming into a service. Later I want to retrieve certain amounts of that data by timestamp. I have to assume that there will be a lot of data. When I retrieve the data, I will be displaying it in some range (1 day, 1 week, 1 month, etc).

**What I've Tried**

I don't want to burn the rubber off my table by writing a WHERE timestamp < 1 WEEK, when it will have to read a years worth of rows. So, what I'm trying now, is to write the data to mini tables, one_week_data, one_month_data. Then, in a cron job, I can clean up those tables, at an interval instead of on client request, so it doesn't need to be efficient.

If I have no unique key constraints, this works just fine, I just pop the data in my tables and leave, but...

**Problem with What I've Tried**

With the way my data streams into my service, I cannot 100% guarantee that my data will not be duplicated. So, I put a Unique index on each table for the ID and the Timestamp. I thought that the indexes would just effect the column in the table the index was added to, but it seems to trigger when I add data to table 2. Saying that it's breaking the unique key constraint.

**So...**

- Is there a way to force a unique index to only affect a given table?
- Is there a way to have the data in one master table and index time slices?
- Is there something else I'm not seeing that would be more effective entirely?

**Database**

Very roughly

```
CREATE TABLE oneday (
  `id`        int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_id`   varchar(36),
  `timestamp` timestamp(6),
  {{ Some data fields }},
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `data_id_timestamp` (`data_id`,`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE oneweek (
  `id`        int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_id`   varchar(36),
  `timestamp` timestamp(6),
  {{ Some data fields }},
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `data_id_timestamp` (`data_id`,`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I still don't understand what problem you're actually tring to solve - but maybe that says more about my limitations :-(

Comment: @Strawberry - I'm not sure where I lost you, but my general premise is that currently I have multiple tables that are subsets of one big table. 1 day data < 1 week data < 1 month data. All entries in 1 day data are also in 1 month data, but not all entries in 1 month data are in 1 day. But, because they are identical data points, they refuse to insert, because they break uniqueness rules for data_id_timestamp.

Comment: why  you simply don't create a set of view .. one for each  ..  "miniquery" ????  avoiding data duplication  ..

Comment: In which case, I think I would reject the general premise. :-( I woudln't create a view either. Queries are what SQL is good at, and queries is what I would use - (but I might also look at partitioning, if appropriate)

Comment: .. @Strawberry  ..  I don't know if it can help but I too find it hard to understand the question ..

Comment: @scaisEdge - I apologize for the confusion. I don't use MySQL often, but it looks like creating views is exactly what I was looking for. I just couldn't find it earlier. If you'd like to add that as an answer, I would be willing to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of several minitable  .. with replicated  data and a lot of issue related to mantain the correct data integrity

you could use a several views  .. each of these specifically desined  for r the date range you need

```
  create view_oneday as 
  select  col1,  ..coln 
  from you_table
  where date(your_date_col)  = curdate() 


  create view_onewee as 
  select  col1,  ..coln 
  from you_table
  where week(your_date_col)  = week(curdate()) 

   ...
```

Comment: Personally, I see no advantage in doing this over simply executing the underlying queries as and when required.